# Is there a way to add a user to several groups (in bulk) in Keycloak using Keycloak Admin REST API?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

At the moment I am adding the user to one group at a time using this endpoint:

```
PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/groups/{groupId}
```

In my use case it would be beneficial to perform the affectations in bulk, so far I haven't found a documented way of doing so, is there a way to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
PUT /{realm}/users/{id}
```

It's in the documentation, but it doesn't work.

I started discussion on [github](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/8552)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30031074)

Answer (score 2):

You could try to update the full user data

`PUT /{realm}/users/{id}`

with a **partial** `UserRepresentation` containing a minimal json with "groups" array only ?

I see that nearly all fields are marked as optional:
cfr https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/12.0/rest-api/index.html#_userrepresentation

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think it's a good workaround. However I still haven't got it to work. Tried in the body: { groups: [ "group-1-id", "group-2-id" ] } it gave code 200 but didn't add the user to the groups, and { groups: [ { id: "group-1-id" }, { id: "group-2-id" } ] } which gave a code 500

Comment: Did you try with the group **id** (ex "fcc0d684-f80b-4351-a441-49c8170c652c") and not the group name (ex: "my-group") ?

Comment: Yes exactly, the group id. I think the feature I'm looking for is unfortunately not available in  Keycloak. I needed it for atomicity since I modify in Keycloak and in a local database but for now I'm handling it by rolling back if one PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/groups/{groupId} fails and I undo the changed ones if there were any.

Answer (score 1):

The following way still works as of `Keycloak` v21.0.2 but is super uncomfortable, especially in case when one group should be joined and another should be left:

```
PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/groups/{groupId}
```

In documentation for [UserRepresentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/21.0.2/rest-api/#_userrepresentation) the entry `groups` is listed as `< string > array`, however fetching user with

```
GET /{realm}/users/{id}
```

returns a `UserRepresentation` that is lacking the entry `groups` (in my case the user was part of a group, so it was not empty).

When updating a user with

```
PUT /{realm}/users/{id}
```

with a minimal `UserRepresentation` with only `groups` defined like this:

```
{"groups":["cdcb76bd-ebb1-48ef-bec2-a81aad370746"]}
```

the `SuccessCode` `204` is returned, but nothing changed (no removing unmentioned group or adding new group).

This is still an active issue as of May 2023, see here: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/9354.